# Using the $_FILES superglobal

Tags: php, file, superglobals

I would like to use  `$_FILES['name']['size']` to see if the size of the file being uploaded is bigger than 1MB. How can I do this? What do I use for the size in my if statement?

Like this?:

```
if ( $_FILES['name']['size'] >= 1Mb) {
    // do this;
}
```

Comment: -1: This is aptly covered in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

No, since that is a string and the size is an integer in terms of bytes.

Given that 1Mb is 1000Kb is 1,000,000b, this will work:

```
if ( $_FILES['name']['size'] >= 1 * 1000 * 1000)
```

I'm assuming though that you mean MB, since files are expressed in bytes (B) instead of bits (b). In that case, use 1024 instead of 1000 (1MB = 1024KB. 1KB = 1024B).

Comment: No <dons pedantic hat>. The OP was comparing with 1Mb which is a megabit. He may want to do that, and as such I'm giving another response under the assumption that he was wrong.

Comment: "I would like to use $_FILES['name']['size'] to see if the size of the file being uploaded is bigger than 1MB"

Comment: I suppose you mean MB and MiB. Mb would be Megabit, MB megabyte. MiB, however, is MebiByte.

Comment: Actually, it now turns out that the MB suffix also refers to 1000 according to the IEEE, such that I should be using MiB for my point.

Answer (score 2):

The size is represented in bytes. 1 MB is 1024 * 1024 bytes.

```
if ( $_FILES['name']['size'] >= 1024 * 1024) {
    // do this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The size value is in bytes. so 1MB is 1048576

[MB -> byte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte)

[PHP $_FILES superglobal array info](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php#89674)

Answer (score -1):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> `$_FILES['userfile']['size']`
>
> The size, **in bytes**, of the uploaded file.

1MB is *(1024*1024)* bytes (or 1048576B), so:

```
if ($_FILES['name']['size'] >= 1024*1024) {
    // do this;
}
```

*Please use the documentation.*